# Combining regex expressions

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions - one which checks for character length (max 50 characters):

```
reMatch(value,"^.{0,50}$")
```

and another to ensure the first letter of each word is always uppercase:

```
^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$
```

I would like to combine the latter with reMatch syntax so that both checks are triggered on the same attribute. All the best and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `^(?=.{0,50}$)(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much - that works! :)